# Ошибка: failed to load 'NvCpl.dll' library.

Tags: c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не работает программа. Постоянно выдает

> failed to load 'NvCpl.dll' library.

Программа находится в папке с библиотекой nvcpl.dll

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef BOOL (__cdecl* NvCplGetThermalSettings)(IN UINT nWindowsMonitorNumber,OUT DWORD* pdwCoreTemp,OUT DWORD* pdwAmbientTemp,OUT DWORD* pdwUpperLimit);
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  HMODULE hNV=LoadLibrary(TEXT("nvcpl.dll"));
  if(hNV==NULL)
    printf("failed to load 'NvCpl.dll' library.\n");
  else
  {
    NvCplGetThermalSettings fNvCplGetThermalSettings=(NvCplGetThermalSettings)GetProcAddress(hNV,"NvCplGetThermalSettings");
    if(fNvCplGetThermalSettings==NULL)
      printf("failed to get function address 'NvCplGetThermalSettings()'.\n");
    else
    {
      unsigned long current;
      unsigned long ambient;
      unsigned long limit;
      if(fNvCplGetThermalSettings(0,& current,&ambient,&limit)==false)
        printf("failed to aquire current gpu temperature.\n");
      else
        printf("gpu temperature: %d\n",current);
    }
    FreeLibrary(hNV);
  }
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Хм. Попробуйте для отладки указать _полный_ путь.

Кстати, а что возвращает [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: Полный путь пробывал вводить тоже самое получается.